# Visual Studio 2019 becomes unresponsive when attaching to process

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm not understanding why but my Visual Studio is always becoming unresponsive whenever I'm trying to debug(attaching to process w3wp). The application which I'm trying to debug is a .NET MVC app and is pretty memory intensive.

However, I do have a 16GB RAM in my laptop and the CPU is currently 77%(sometimes even lesser) used but then what is the problem? It was working fine till yesterday! Also, I have to kill the VS process every time from Task Manager because otherwise my VS seems to remain stuck like this forever! I've restarted Visual Studio and my system multiple times since the last 7-8 hours, cleared temp and cached files, freed up some space in my hard drive(currently about 125GB is left) etc. but with no luck.

[image]

Comment: Had the same problem in the past when attempting to attach VS2019 debugger to a running IIS w3wp.exe process. After doing some investigation (it's already reported on VS forums) i was realized that it was trying to find the process to attach to but it can't. The only "workaround" i found was to kill Remote Debugger process and reattach. Re-attaching works fine.

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ how can I kill the remote debugger process(w3wp right)? VS is not responding.

Comment: Hi The Inquisitive Coder, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. 
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying, finally, restarting my IIS Server, recycling of App Pool fixed the issue for me. Hope my answer benefits others as well :)